# Algorithm for finding reoccurring patterns in a string

Tags: string, algorithm, machine-learning, pattern-matching

I am looking for an algorithm which will find reoccurring patterns in a string.

I have a string of data which contains transactions.
Each transaction contains properties (name/ values).
The format of these transactions is unknown, they may be in JSON, XML or any other string format.
However, whatever their format may be, its structure is identical to all them though their content may change.
I would like to use an algorithm which can identify the transactions in the string based on a repeating pattern (unknown).

For example, the following string contains 2 transaction:

```
<m><a>Hello</a><b>World</b></m><m><a>Good</a><b>Bye</b></m>
```

The following string also contains 2 transactions:

```
##start##First Transaction##end####start##Second Transaction##end
```

What algorithm should I use?

Comment: Not sure I am following, how should you identify that the 2nd for example is not actually containing 6 transactions: (start, First Transaction, end, start, Second Transaction, end)?

Comment: Are you sure you can't determine the format of the data through a side-channel? Is there no way the source of the data can't provide you with the MIME-type, for example?

Comment: I am looking for a generic solution that will identify any transaction structure and not in a specific format. It can do so only if it identifies that a certain pattern repeats itself.
The 2nd example has 2 transactions:
1: ##start##First Transaction##end##
2: ##start##Second Transaction##end##

Comment: @DoronNeumann Why? What's the logic? Why is the 2nd example not containing 6 transactions, and is `(start, First Transaction, end, start, Second Transaction, end)` Please explain why the 6 transactions solution I proposed is NOT correct.

Comment: @amit Suppose the data is coming from a user management system outputting a user list in a textual proprietary protocol.
The protocol has a the token ##start## before each user data, then the username, then his address and finally the user record ends with ##end##.
Is that more clear? This is an example, when speaking of a transaction, I mean a logical unit of data.

Comment: When the format of the string is unknown and may be any string format, you're asking the impossible, especially if the unknown format can contain meaningful keywords that look like actions. Your best bet is to implement a few real formats like XML and then decide which to use by a simple heuristic: If it contains matched pairs of angular brackets, it's XML, if it has many consecutive hash signs, it's your second format, and so on.

Comment: @DoronNeumann This makes no sense, because you are asking for an algorithm to automatically figure out what is the parsing scheme used by this user management. If it was possible, nobody would write a [xml schema](http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/), but people do write these.

Comment: @amit An algorithm for finding reoccurring patterns in a string does make sense for someone who would need such an algorithm.
If you don't know the answer - just don't comment.

Comment: @DoronNeumann - What everyone is trying to tell you is that an input string can be mapped to infinitely many different outputs, if you don't specify any rules in advance about how the input should be parsed.  Your best bet would be to reduce your possible set of input formats from "infinite" to "several", and create code to specifically handle those several formats.  If you insist that you need to be able to handle any possible input format, then you may want to do research into machine learning algorithms, and train the algorithm to map different formats into the same transactions.

Comment: amit is right, there's no unique solution for your problem. E.g. in the first example, I think the transactions are (m, a>Hello</a, b>World</b, /m, m, a>Good</a, b>Byte</b, /m). Unless you clearly define the goal and side conditions that make the problem solvable, your question is unanswerable

Comment: Also you're *not* searching for an algorithm to "find reoccurring patterns in a string", that would be easy. You're looking for something much more contrived, in the realm of artificial intelligence

Comment: I agree that this problem is part of the machine learning realm.

Comment: @DoronNeumann - In that case, this question should be closed.  Asking for an entire machine learning algorithm implementation is beyond the scope of this site.

Answer (score 1):

I have no solution, but some thought about the matter:

You could try to split your inputs in chunks and use a kind of `diff` algorithm on these chunks. With enough samples you could identify the delimiters.

I tried to diff the following strings:

- `<m><a>Hello</a><b>World</`
- `b></m><m><a>Good</a><b>Bye</b></m>`

And it gives me the following delimiters:

- `<m><a>`
- `</a><b>`

Obsiously you should repeat the operation with more samples and different chunks size. This would give you the probable delimiters, not a 100% certain answer.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem

Also you can take a look at this paper which uses n-grams frequencies to find delimiters:

http://people.cs.vt.edu/danfeng/papers/ICNP-12.pdf